# How to write symbol in pic using latex

Tags: symbols

[image][image: S like symbol]

How to write s like symbol shown in attached pic in latex. tag symbols

Comment: I have looked for this symbol too and I am not sure how to get it. It may be a proprietary font of some sorts...

Comment: Were did you see this symbol? And what is it suposed to mean?

Comment: It is a math or text symbol? Where is the base line of the symbol. What's its size compared to lower and uppercase letters?

Comment: please see new pic attached

Comment: it looks like something specific to a particular font and without the original source, might be hard to trace back. if you have a pdf of the document that you could link to, we may be able to identify the font.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

in the document preamble and

```
\mathscr{S}
```

for the symbol (in math mode).

[image: Symbol]

Note that you can often use

http://detexify.kirelabs.org

or

http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

to find out yourself.